# How to return inner join data in hibernate named query?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, join, named-query

I want to put inner join via `named query` between product_category and product_sub_category tables. I am `creating named query` like:

```
<sql-query name="categoryList">
    <![CDATA[select *
    from product_sub_category psc
    inner join product_category pc on psc.product_category_id = pc.id]]>
    <return alias="pc" class="com.test.application.details.ProductCategoryDetail" />
    <return-join alias="psc" property="pc.productSubDetail"></return-join>  
    </sql-query>
```

I have not created any mapping in hibernate for this. I just want to return data with both the tables. Here is `ProductCategoryDetail.java` :

```
public class ProductCategoryDetail
{

    private String title ;
    private ArrayList<ProductSubDetail> productSubDetail ;

     public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title)
    {
        this.title = title;
    }                     
    public ArrayList<ProductSubDetail> getProductSubDetail() {
        return productSubDetail;
    }

    public void setProductSubDetail(ArrayList<ProductSubDetail>   productSubDetail) {
        this.productSubDetail = productSubDetail;
    }

}
```

It is not working. I am getting **Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: categoryList**.

**What wrong am I doing in it?**

Thanks :-)

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace please

Comment: @Jens Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: categoryList

Comment: Add the **complete** Stacktrace to your question not as a comment

Comment: why are you doing so ?. You can use hibernate mapping for it.